# How to pull the starting view for document using the Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

How can I use the Revit API to get the Starting View for a `Document`?  The equivalent way to access it using the user interface is seen below:

[image: Starting View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [Revit Lookup tool](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) and browsed through the database to find a class called `StartingViewSettings` with the property `ViewId` that will get me the `ElementId` of the starting view.  My actual code for getting the view is below

```
FilteredElementCollector startingViewSettingsCollector = 
  new FilteredElementCollector(document);
startingViewSettingsCollector.OfClass(typeof(StartingViewSettings));

View startingView = null;

foreach(StartingViewSettings settings in startingViewSettingsCollector)
{
    startingView = (View)document.GetElement(settings.ViewId);
}
```

[image: Revit Lookup - Starting View]